# FileInfo Fails on *Short* Path Name

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, fileinfo, pathname

Even if I use a shortened path, (.Net) FileInfo() fails saying it is too long!

I was having problems with long paths, so I made calls to (Win32) GetShortPathNameW, which returns a very nicely sculpted short name like:
"C:\temp\Test\targ1\FIRSTH~1\SECOND~1\SumStuff.txt.somethingTooLong.junk".

Even though this is only 72 characters long, (.Net) FileInfo() throws an exception saying: "The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Yes, the LFN is too long (>400 chars), but it looks fine when shortened.
Is .Net converting it back to long?

(Using .Net 3.5 (lowest common denominator) under Windows 10.)

```
    // code below is extremely abbreviated
    [DllImport ( "kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int GetShortPathNameW ( string path, StringBuilder Buffer, int bufferSize);
    …
    int PathLength = GetShortPathNameW ( Path_, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
    …
    FileInfo FileMeta = new FileInfo ( buffer.ToString());
    // is fine if the LFN is short (<260)
    // but exception using a shortened path name
```

OK I am adding this example that I compiled and ran, with the same error. I can't help but feel that the Unicode/Marshalling debate is a distraction from my real issue:

```
    // simplified example (should have started with this)
    static void Main ( string[] args)
    {
    FileInfo FileMeta = new FileInfo ( @"C:\temp\Test\targ1\FIRSTH~1\SECOND~1\SumStuff.txt.somethingTooLong.junk");
    Console.WriteLine ( "Size: " + FileMeta.Length.ToString());
    }
```

Still get the same return:

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.  
    at System.IO.Path.SafeSetStackPointerValue(Char* buffer, Int32 index, Char value)  
    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck)  
    at System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String fileName)  
    at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Projects\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 12
```

Comment: You cannot pass a StringBuilder.  See Pin Voke : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetShortPathName.html

Comment: [More on new .NET path handling](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/06/21/more-on-new-net-path-handling/). [Long Paths in .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton/).

Comment: @jdweng: You may be right, but that's exactly what the second example on that page uses.

Comment: No.  The 2nd example there is a Marshal method that is used (MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)) That converts the string builder to a LPTStr.  That Marshal method "MAY" be the default that is used in c#, but I not sure.  I had this discussion with somebody a few weeks ago and I'm a Doubting Thomas and do not believe what I do not see in writing.  Microsoft is very bad at the documentation.

Comment: @jdweng is incorrect. Your pinvoke declaration is fine. StringBuilder is correct.

Comment: I'm correct again.  Nothing I said is wrong.  Show me the documentation if anything I said was incorrect.

Comment: @jdweng for example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-strings I'm not actually interested in trying to convince you. I just want to repair the damage done by your erroneous statement. I want the asker of the question to know that what you said is wrong.

Comment: There is nothing I said that was wrong so no repair is required.  the current code does not have any marshal conversions and c# is using defaults (which are not defined any place).  The Marshal Statements should be added like in PinVoke code.

Comment: @jdweng encoding is determined here by CharSet.Unicode. Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/specifying-a-character-set?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Encoding has nothing to do with issue!!!

Comment: @jdweng Correct. Which what I have been saying. The marshaling code is fine. The issue relates to the system handling of long file names. My point has been to correct the misinformation that you have spread about the marshaling.

Comment: Where is [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] in the posted code?  It is only at Pinvoke!!!

Comment: @jdweng Like I said, `CharSet.Unicode` in the `DllImport` attribute removes the need for that. Do bear in mind that there people who have actually written and called pinvoke methods.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2585171/685760) has some other suggestions on how to do this. The last question also has a comment on using a uint rather than int for windows 10 (maybe where you are passing in buffer.Capacity). This isn't really meant to be an answer, just possibly some other suggestions you could try.

Comment: Dunno if this helps but, [starting in Windows 10, version 1607, MAX_PATH limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior.](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html)