# Shorten long file path name using kernel32.dll in c#

Tags: c#, kernel32

I'm trying to convert long file path to a short file path. Tried with all signatures of GetShortPathName available in kernel32.dll mentioned below . But all return an empty string instead of a short file path.Testing using a c# windows app(.net framework 4.6.1) on a 64-bit machine in win 10. Please let me know how to get a short file path.Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint GetShortPathName(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    string lpszLongPath,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    StringBuilder lpszShortPath,
    uint cchBuffer);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint GetShortPathName(string lpszLongPath, char[] lpszShortPath, int cchBuffer);


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "GetShortPathNameW", 
    SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetShortPathName(string pathName, System.Text.StringBuilder shortName, int 
    cbShortName);

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string longFilePath = @"C:\E\Authors files\GOLD\ddd Retail Leases\ddd Owned or Co-Owned Centres (including Property Income Fund Properties) – Managed by ddd\Garden City Booragoon (WA)\Specialty Leases & Deeds\Shop 12A\35120-#5337137, v1 _VICProduction1_ - Shop xxx - Garden City, Booragoon - D.C.K Australia Pty Ltd t_as Lovisa - Executed Deed of Assignment and Variation of Lease and Consent to Assignment   - WorkSite Acrobat Integration.pdf";


        string s1 = ShortPath(longFilePath);
         string s2=ToShortPathName(longFilePath);            
        string s3 = GetShortPathName(longFilePath);

    }

    public static string ToShortPathName(string longName)
    {
        uint bufferSize = 256;           
        StringBuilder shortNameBuffer = new StringBuilder((int)bufferSize);
        GetShortPathName(longName, shortNameBuffer, bufferSize);
        return shortNameBuffer.ToString();
    }

    public string ShortPath(string longpath)
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[256];
        GetShortPathName(longpath, buffer, buffer.Length);
        return new string(buffer);
    }

    public static string GetShortPathName(string longFileName)
    {           
        uint bufferSize = 256;                       
        StringBuilder shortNameBuffer = new StringBuilder((int)bufferSize);
        uint result = GetShortPathName(longFileName, shortNameBuffer, bufferSize);
        return shortNameBuffer.ToString();
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GetShortPathNameA not working in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585171/getshortpathnamea-not-working-in-c-sharp)

Comment: no. Above link does not answer my question. It gives same empty value.

Comment: Appreciate if anyone can suggest how to get this working. It just returns an empty value. No error is thrown

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, but trick is to prepend `"\\?\"` to the path

```
const int MAX_PATH = 255;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "GetShortPathNameW", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetShortPathName(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    string pathName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    StringBuilder shortName, int cbShortName);

public static string GetShortPath(string path)
{
    var shortPath = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
    GetShortPathName($"\\\\?\\{path}", shortPath, MAX_PATH);
    var shortenedPath = shortPath.ToString();
    return shortenedPath.Replace("\\\\?\\", string.Empty);
}

var longPath = @"C:\E\Authors files\GOLD\ddd Retail Leases\ddd Owned or Co-Owned Centres (including Property Income Fund Properties) – Managed by ddd\Garden City Booragoon (WA)\Specialty Leases & Deeds\Shop 12A\35120-#5337137, v1 _VICProduction1_ - Shop xxx - Garden City, Booragoon - D.C.K Australia Pty Ltd t_as Lovisa - Executed Deed of Assignment and Variation of Lease and Consent to Assignment   - WorkSite Acrobat Integration.pdf";
var shortenedPath = GetShortPath(longPath);
```

Resource:

[Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry)

Comment: Damn, a useful resurrection. Doesn't happen often